# argument of type "x" is incompatible with parameter of type x

Tags: c, function

There is a `union`:

```
typedef union {
    RF_CmdHandle ch;                              
    uint16_t     availRatCh;                     
    bool         bRadioState;                     
    void         *pScheduleMap;                   
} RF_InfoVal;
```

which is used by a function:

```
RF_Stat RF_getInfo(RF_Handle h, RF_InfoType type, RF_InfoVal *pValue)
```

My variables are as following:

```
RF_handle handle;
RF_InfoType infoType = 0;
RF_InfoVal info;
```

when I use the function like this:

```
RF_Stat status =  RF_getInfo(handle, infoType, info);
```

I get the following error:

```
argument of type "RF_InfoVal" is incompatible with parameter of type RF_InfoVal.
```

I would be very happy about an explanation what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: make that `RF_InfoVal *info;` or call as `RF_getInfo(handle, infoType, &info);`

Comment: The function takes a pointer to a union as argument,. You are giving it a union

Comment: Please always copy&paste your exact error message and don't type from your memory. You must have missed a '*' from the error message.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: First suggestion will crash at runtime without malloc, so probably it would be better not to confuse OP.

Comment: @Paul Ogilvie that worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing wrong is that you aren't paying attention to what you're reading. **Punctuation matters.** `RF_InfoVal` and `RF_InfoVal*` are not the same thing. The first is a union, the second is a pointer to a union.

The error message that you retranscribed had a `*`. That `*` is important.

Here we can figure out that you made a mistake when retranscribing the error message — but that's because the mistake you made there is the same mistake that you made in your code. You should never retranscribe an error message. **Always copy-paste**. The same goes for your code: [always copy-paste a full piece of code that reproduces the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: yes thats true! Next time it will be a copy and paste :D.